# Как переопределить метод статической генерации объекта?

Tags: java

У меня есть два класса для записей: сохранение в БД и сохранение в файл. Оба класса реализуют интерфейс `RecordsSaver`:

```
public interface RecordsSaver {
    public void saveRecond();
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что каждый из классов следует обязать реализовать метод статической генерации `getRecordsSaver`. Однако, если в интерфейсе реализовать такой статический метод, его уже нельзя переопределить в классе, аналогично с абстрактными классами.

Подскажите, как или переопределить метод, или есть какие-то другие выходы из данной ситуации?

Comment: А использование этого всего как у вас выглядит? `FileRecordSaver.getRecordSaver( record ).saveRecord()`?

Comment: Как насчет того, чтобы посмотреть в сторону шаблона проектирования "фабрика"?

Comment: @cache, даже если идти таким путем (мне он даже кажется в чем-то предпочтительнее, проблема остается та же).

Comment: @zRrr, ну... Да :). Я пришел к более правильному решению, сейчас в ответ напишу.

Answer (score 1):

Я немного ошибся в задумке работы с БД (я хотел, чтобы добавление файлов было доступно отовсюду).

Самым правильным вариантом было не использовать статические методы в БД, а создать класс, который управляет работой с БД. В результате, нет потребности пытаться сделать единственный объект БД (т.е. фабричный метод или статические внутренние переменные), так как в управляющем классе будет создаваться только один экземпляр. Теперь весь код обращается к управляющему классу. И главный плюс, который я из этого извлек - при изменении работы с БД, меняется только один класс.